# Why does document.evaluate succeed in Firebug but fail in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath, document.evaluate

browser.getEval function in selenium makes iterateNext return null ..Otherwise in firebug it returns a value(same script)

```
document.evaluate("//button[text()='Save']",
                  document, 
                  null,
                  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
                  null)
        .iterateNext()
        .disabled;
```

returns true

But

```
browser.getEval("document.evaluate(\"//button[text()='Save']\", 
                                     document,
                                     null,
                                     XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
                                     null)
                         .iterateNext()
                         .disabled;");
```

returns that error as :

> "com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Threw an exception: res.iterateNext() is null "

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `document.evaluate` with `this.browserbot.getUserWindow().document.evaluate`

Comment: Are you using Selenium IDE or RC? If RC, what client language are you using? Perhaps you could provide a little more sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.document.evaluate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
document.evaluate
```

with

```
selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.evaluate
```